# Окно в окне при помощи разных файлов Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-import

Всем привет, буду очень благодарен за разъяснение, постараюсь отчетливо объяснить суть проблемы, с которой сюда решил обратиться. Имеется текстовый редактор, его я сделал отдельным файлом, вот у меня имеется main файл с пустым окошком и файл notepad, как мне его импортировать, чтобы файл содержался внутри окошка main.
Не мало был бы рад, если показали как это окно notepad внутри окна main перемещать в удобное положение.

*Ниже приведен пример желаемого (рис.1):* [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### ----------
Рисунок 1

## Это мой main:

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import scrolledtext 
win= tk.Tk()
h= 1200
w= 650
photo = tk.PhotoImage (file='Logo.png')
win.iconphoto (False, photo)
win.config (bg='#6e4f5f')
win.title('TimLock Alpha v.0.1')
win.geometry(f"{h}x{w}+1000+350")
win.resizable(False, False)
win.mainloop()
```

## Ниже код текстового редактора:

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog**


def chenge_theme(theme):
    text_fild['bg'] = view_colors[theme]['text_bg']
    text_fild['fg'] = view_colors[theme]['text_fg']
    text_fild['insertbackground'] = view_colors[theme]['cursor']
    text_fild['selectbackground'] = view_colors[theme]['select_bg']


def chenge_fonts(fontss):
    text_fild['font'] = fonts[fontss]['font']


def notepad_exit():
    answer = messagebox.askokcancel('Выход', 'Вы точно хотите выйти?')
    if answer:
        root.destroy()


def open_file():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Выбор файла', filetypes=(('Текстовые документы (*.txt)', '*.txt'), ('Все файлы', '*.*')))
    if file_path:
        text_fild.delete('1.0', END)
        text_fild.insert('1.0', open(file_path, encoding='utf-8').read())


def save_file():
    file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=(('Текстовые документы (*.txt)', '*.txt'), ('Все файлы', '*.*')))
    f = open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    text = text_fild.get('1.0', END)
    f.write(text)
    f.close()

root = Tk()
root.title('Текстовый редактор')
root.geometry('600x700')

main_menu = Menu(root)

file_menu = Menu(main_menu, tearoff=0)
file_menu.add_command(label='Открыть', command=open_file)
file_menu.add_command(label='Сохранить', command=save_file)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label='Закрыть', command=notepad_exit)
root.config(menu=file_menu)

view_menu = Menu(main_menu, tearoff=0)
view_menu_sub = Menu(view_menu, tearoff=0)
font_menu_sub = Menu(view_menu, tearoff=0)
view_menu_sub.add_command(label='Светлая', command=lambda: chenge_theme('light'))
view_menu_sub.add_command(label='Тёмная', command=lambda: chenge_theme('dark'))
view_menu.add_cascade(label='Тема', menu=view_menu_sub)

font_menu_sub.add_command(label='Arial', command=lambda: chenge_fonts('Arial'))
font_menu_sub.add_command(label='Comic Sans MS', command=lambda: chenge_fonts('CSMS'))
font_menu_sub.add_command(label='Times New Roman', command=lambda: chenge_fonts('TNR'))
view_menu.add_cascade(label='Шрифт...', menu=font_menu_sub)
root.config(menu=view_menu)

main_menu.add_cascade(label='Файл', menu=file_menu)
main_menu.add_cascade(label='Вид', menu=view_menu)
root.config(menu=main_menu)

f_text = Frame(root)
f_text.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

view_colors = {
    'light': {
        'text_bg': 'white', 'text_fg': 'black', 'cursor': '#A5A5A5', 'select_bg': '#FAEEDD'
    },
    'dark': {
        'text_bg': 'black', 'text_fg': 'white', 'cursor': 'brown', 'select_bg': 'gray'
    }

}

fonts = {
    'Arial': {
        'font':'Arial 14 bold'
    },
    'CSMS': {
        'font': ('Comic Sans MS', 14, 'bold')
    },
    'TNR': {
        'font': ('Times New Roman', 14, 'bold')
    }
}

text_fild = Text(f_text,
                 bg='white',
                 fg='black',
                 padx=10,
                 pady=10,
                 wrap=WORD,
                 insertbackground='brown',
                 selectbackground='gray',
                 spacing3=10,
                 width=30,
                 font='Arial 14 bold'
                 )
text_fild.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

scroll = Scrollbar(f_text, command=text_fild.yview)
scroll.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
text_fild.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

В первую очередь стоило бы сначала постараться самому найти [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73699657/how-to-open-two-modules-in-one-window-python-tkinter).
Во вторую описать какие варианты решения проблемы были предприняты.

Перепишите код так, чтобы файл можно было подключить как модуль. Для этого опишите весь код блокнота в классе окна, который будет создаваться только если файл запущен, а не подключен как модуль. Примерно так:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog

view_colors = {
    'light': {
        'text_bg': 'white', 'text_fg': 'black', 'cursor': '#A5A5A5', 'select_bg': '#FAEEDD'
    },
    'dark': {
        'text_bg': 'black', 'text_fg': 'white', 'cursor': 'brown', 'select_bg': 'gray'
    }
}

fonts = {
    'Arial': {
        'font':'Arial 14 bold'
    },
    'CSMS': {
        'font': ('Comic Sans MS', 14, 'bold')
    },
    'TNR': {
        'font': ('Times New Roman', 14, 'bold')
    }
}

class NotepadWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root = None):
        super(root)

        self.text_field = Text(
            self,
            bg='white',
            fg='black',
            padx=10,
            pady=10,
            wrap=WORD,
            insertbackground='brown',
            selectbackground='gray',
            spacing3=10,
            width=30,
            font='Arial 14 bold'
        )
        self.text_field.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

        scroll = Scrollbar(self, command=self.text_field.yview)
        scroll.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
        self.text_field.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

    def change_theme(self, theme):
        self.text_field['bg'] = view_colors[theme]['text_bg']
        self.text_field['fg'] = view_colors[theme]['text_fg']
        self.text_field['insertbackground'] = view_colors[theme]['cursor']
        self.text_field['selectbackground'] = view_colors[theme]['select_bg']

    def change_fonts(self, fontsIdx):
        self.text_field['font'] = fonts[fontsIdx]['font']

    def open_file(self):
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Выбор файла', filetypes=(('Текстовые документы (*.txt)', '*.txt'), ('Все файлы', '*.*')))
        if file_path:
            self.text_field.delete('1.0', END)
            self.text_field.insert('1.0', open(file_path, encoding='utf-8').read())

    def save_file(self):
        file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=(('Текстовые документы (*.txt)', '*.txt'), ('Все файлы', '*.*')))
        with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            text = self.text_field.get('1.0', END)
            f.write(text)

    def prepare_menu(self, root, onExit = None):
        def notepad_exit(): # Создаём функцию по нажатию кнопки выход
            answer = messagebox.askokcancel('Выход', 'Вы точно хотите выйти?')
            if answer and onExit:
                onExit()

        main_menu = Menu(root)

        file_menu = Menu(main_menu, tearoff=0)
        file_menu.add_command(label='Открыть', command=self.open_file)
        file_menu.add_command(label='Сохранить', command=self.save_file)
        file_menu.add_separator()
        file_menu.add_command(label='Закрыть', command=notepad_exit)
        main_menu.add_cascade(label='Файл', menu=file_menu)

        view_menu = Menu(main_menu, tearoff=0)
        view_menu_sub = Menu(view_menu, tearoff=0)
        font_menu_sub = Menu(view_menu, tearoff=0)
        view_menu_sub.add_command(label='Светлая', command=lambda: self.change_theme('light'))
        view_menu_sub.add_command(label='Тёмная', command=lambda: self.change_theme('dark'))
        view_menu.add_cascade(label='Тема', menu=view_menu_sub)
        main_menu.add_cascade(label='Вид', menu=view_menu)

        font_menu_sub.add_command(label='Arial', command=lambda: self.change_fonts('Arial'))
        font_menu_sub.add_command(label='Comic Sans MS', command=lambda: self.change_fonts('CSMS'))
        font_menu_sub.add_command(label='Times New Roman', command=lambda: self.change_fonts('TNR'))
        view_menu.add_cascade(label='Шрифт...', menu=font_menu_sub)

        return main_menu


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Текстовый редактор')
    root.geometry('600x700')

    notepad = NotepadWindow(root)
    notepad.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    menu = notepad.prepare_menu(root, lambda: root.destroy())
    root.config(menu=menu)

    root.mainloop()
```

После этого класс можно получить в другом файле и подключить его как обычный Frame.

```py
from tkinter import *
from .notepad import NotepadWindow
win = Tk()
h = 1200
w = 650
photo = PhotoImage (file='Logo.png')
win.iconphoto (False, photo)
win.config (bg='#6e4f5f')
win.title('TimLock Alpha v.0.1')
win.geometry(f"{h}x{w}+1000+350")
win.resizable(False, False)
notepad = NotepadWindow(win) # Создаём экземпляр блокнота с родителем win
notepad.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1) # Размещаем его как обычный Frame
menu = notepad.prepare_menu(win, lamda: win.destroy()) # Получаем меню блокнота с родителем win и его уничтожением по нажатию кнопки "Выход" в меню
win.config(menu=menu) # И прикрепляем как меню окна (либо можно добавить в другое меню)
win.mainloop()
```